# how to set xml layout for button

Tags: android, android-framelayout

i would like to second button position to below first button and width fill and height wrap i am already try relative layout and layout align or set set gravity but its all fail pls give me solution for this .

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:text="Vibrate"
    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!--
     This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows.

-->

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStartService"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.15"
            android:text="@string/start_service" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStopService"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/stop_service" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Using horizontal orientation in a LinearLayout is the problem here.  use a vertical orientation if you want the 2nd button to be below the  first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..  you ahve given **orientation**  **horizontal** `android:orientation="horizontal"` then it'll not come below `android:orientation="vertical"`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStartService"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/start_service" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStopService"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/stop_service" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

For **RelativeLayout**  use `android:layout_below="@+id/btnStartService"` for second **button**

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
                style="?buttonBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/black_overlay"
                tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnStartService"
                    style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/start_service" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnStopService"
                    style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnStartService"
                    android:text="@string/stop_service" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStartService"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.15"
            android:text="@string/start_service" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStopService"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnStartService"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/stop_service" />
```

add the  android:layout_below="@+id/btnStartService" to your desired object to be align.

Answer (score -1):

Use a Relative Layout for those two buttons. In the second button , there is a property called "layout_below" -> Give the id of the first button in this.

Then your second button will come below the first button

Comment: Relative layout is unnecessary and requires additional resources to render.  Just use a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="vertical"` for something so simple.

Comment: Your answer is not incorrect, the methods used are simply unnecessary.